# The set method in useState variable not updating the state variable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-state

I'm working on an application that has a chat functionality. When a chat from new user comes in, the store will update an array of all the chats, and that array will be passed down to a child component as a prop. Any time the chats array updates, the child component runs a useEffect to perform some functions. I have following code in the child component to detect update in the chats array:

```js
const App = (props: propsData) => {
let [filtered, setFiltered] = useState([])
let [chats, setChats] = useState({active: [], inactive: []})

  useEffect(()=>{  
    const temp: any = {active: [], inactive: []};
    props.payload.conversations.forEach((element: any) => {
        const status = element.status.toLowerCase(); // element.status can be 'Active' or 'Inactive'
        temp[status].push(element);
            
    });
    console.log(temp) // prints expected output: {active: [some array], inactive: [some array]}
    
    setChats(temp); // this doesn't set the value to 'chats'
    
    console.log(chats) // prints {active: [], inactive: []}
    
    filterChats(); // function combines together the 'active' and 'inacive' arrays in 'chats' 
                   // object to assign to 'filtered' array.
  }, [props.payload.conversations.length])

  return(
    <div>
      {
        filtered.map((item: any) => (
          <div>
            //display item data here
          </div>
        )
        )
    </div
  )
}
export default App;
```

My problem is that the setter function `setChats(temp)` is not setting the value of `chats` if I explicitly assign its as `chats=temp`it works, but the setter method isn't working. I've tried not giving any default favlue, typecasting along with giving a default value but nothing is working.

Comment: How are you using chats variable?

Comment: @Roberto Zvjerković Nothing complicated. I'm assigning `chats.active` or `chats.inactive` to `filtered` if I only need to display active or inactive chats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState` is an async function.
So putting a `console.log(state)` right after setting it will most likely show the former value, as it doesn't actually finish updating the state until the log command is run.
What you can do is add a `useEffect` that has the relevant state as a dependency to check the value.

i.e -

```js
   useEffect(() => {
      console.log(chats);
   }, [chats]);
```

Comment: Ohh wow I feel stupid. So `setChats` updates `chats` and the `filterChats` function called from the useEffect updates `filtered` which I'm looping over in jsx. I have created another effect for `chats` like you said, and inside it I'm calling `filterChats`. Thanks!