# State not immediately updating, even with prevState

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I'm trying to assign "email" (which is a state) to "refEmail.current.value".

So I do `setEmail(response.data)` and when I do a `console.log(response.data)`, I have the expected data, but if I do immediately after a `console.log(email)`, I still have the default value of my state. I tried using prevState but it doesn't change anything: `setEmail(prevState => prevState, response.data)`

This is my code:

```
const EditProfilModal = () => {

  const [email, setEmail] = useState('exemple') 

  const refFirstname = useRef();
  const refLastname = useRef();
  const refEmail = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const toFetchEmail = async () => {
      try {
        const params = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).user_id;
        const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4200/api/user/${params}`);
        setEmail(prevState => prevState, response.data)        
        console.log(response.data)
        console.log(email);
      } catch (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    };
    toFetchEmail()
    refFirstname.current.value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).user_firstname;
    refLastname.current.value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).user_lastname;
    refEmail.current.value = email;
  }, []);

  return (.....)
```

So, the first console.log return the expected data, but the second return the default value (example) instead of the expected data. Why, and how to update the state immediately?

Comment: You can't update it immediately. The value of email doesn't change until the line where it's assigned to is reached again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The set method in useState variable not updating the state variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69375411/the-set-method-in-usestate-variable-not-updating-the-state-variable)

Answer (score 0):

This is the same issue mentioned in [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)
and
[setState in react functional components is not being assigned property with assigned objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69763982/setstate-in-react-functional-components-is-not-being-assigned-property-with-assi/69764063#69764063)

React setState or useState function will not instantly change your variable, it is an asynchronous process that will only set your value on its next render,

```
console.log(email)
setEmail(newEmail)
console.log(email)
```

This code show same log as current property is not yet updated with the new one, To check the change of a state variable you can check it outside your function (before the return of component) or in a useEffect

```
useEffect(()=> {
    conole.log(email) // this will console latest value on your every `email` update
 },[email])
```

or you can simply console it before you return the HTML, or inside HTML, the value will automatically update on its next render

```
const EditProfilModal = () => {

  const [email, setEmail] = useState('exemple') 

  const refFirstname = useRef();
  const refLastname = useRef();
  const refEmail = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const toFetchEmail = async () => {
      try {
        const params = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).user_id;
        const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4200/api/user/${params}`);
        setEmail(prevState => prevState, response.data)        
        console.log(response.data)
       } catch (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    };
    toFetchEmail()
    refFirstname.current.value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).user_firstname;
    refLastname.current.value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).user_lastname;
    refEmail.current.value = email;
  }, []);
  console.log(email);  //This will console email on every render, you can check the update each time. it always consoles the latest updated value.
  return (.....)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help but i'm already using useEffect as it's shown in my code and even  adding [email] as dependancie of my useEffect d'ont change anything, when i do :

  useEffect(()=> {
    console.log(email)
 },[email])

the console.log returns me "exemple" and not the response.data as expected :/

Comment: you can write any number off use effects in component, keep the current useEffect as same
and create a new one with email dependency. I have suggested to methods to check the email changes. both will work fine

Comment: Yes, i have keep my code and just added this :

  useEffect(() => {
    refEmail.current.value = email;
  }, [email]);

but ref.current.value is still equal to "exemple"